# Convert System.Net.MailMessage to OpenPop.Mime.Message

Tags: c#, .net, imap, openpop

Ho do I Can Convert

> System.Net.MailMessage

to

> OpenPop.Mime.Message

to create new Message of OpenPop.Mime.Message.
First , I use below code to Extract RawMessage of the MailMessage, then send It to constructor of the OpenPop.Mime.Message to create an instance of the Message, But if email contain Persian content, for example the Display Name of the Sender is Persian ("مسعود بهرامی"), After convert sender is changed to "??????????"`

```
private const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    private static readonly Type MailWriter = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    private static readonly ConstructorInfo MailWriterConstructor = MailWriter.GetConstructor(Flags, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo CloseMethod = MailWriter.GetMethod("Close", Flags);
    private static readonly MethodInfo SendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", Flags);

    /// <summary>
    /// A little hack to determine the number of parameters that we
    /// need to pass to the SaveMethod.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly bool IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive = SendMethod.GetParameters().Length == 3;

    /// <summary>
    /// The raw contents of this MailMessage as a MemoryStream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The caller.</param>
    /// <returns>A MemoryStream with the raw contents of this MailMessage.</returns>
    public static byte[] RawMessage(this MailMessage self)
    {
        var result = new MemoryStream();

        var mailWriter = MailWriterConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { result });
        SendMethod.Invoke(self, Flags, null, IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive ? new[] { mailWriter, true, true } : new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);

        return null;

        //result = new MemoryStream(result);
        //result = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.ToArray().ToString()));

        CloseMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, Flags, null, new object[] { }, null);

        //return result;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Does `OpenPop.Mime.Message` have a constructor and property setters you can use?  Does `System.Net.MailMessage` have the information you need to constructor the other one?  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @David OpenPop.Mime.Message only one constructor, with byte[] of the Emial

Comment: Instead of being forced to use gross hacks to convert between OpenPOP's Message object and System.Net.Mail's MailMessage objects, why not just use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) so that you can do SMTP and POP3 (and IMAP) using a single library?

Comment: Also, MimeKit (and MailKit by extension) are much better at handling charset conversion than any other open source mail library.

Comment: @jstedfast thanks, but now i can't change my library to MailKit

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like System.Net.MailMessage exposes any methods that'll do the byte[] formatting for you, so you'll have to create a ToByteArray method to construct a byte array that you can pass to the constructor of OpenPop.Mime.Message in order to create a message object. You can deduce the format of the array that you need, from the following system:

[Converting a Gmail API Message into an OpenPop Mime message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268191/converting-a-gmail-api-message-into-an-openpop-mime-message)

This doesn't exactly solve your problem, but I hope it gives you enough to work with.

Comment: As I said before,   RawMessage extension for MailMessage extract rawMessage of the MailMessage but if email contain Persian content, Persian correcter doesn't show properly  . "?????????"

Comment: Non-ASCII characters tend to be handled like attachments, so you may have to treat them as such. I'm aware I didn't answer your question entirely - I just wanted to give you enough clues to work with. Use the Gmail API to learn the format that the OpenPop message requires, and take it from there :)